# Windows 10 is not booting from grub menu after dual booting Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 85 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1           1,026,048   163,896,156   162,870,109   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2         163,897,344   164,911,103     1,013,760  27 Hidden NTFS (Recovery Environment)
/dev/sda3         166,756,352   874,369,023   707,612,672   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         874,371,070   976,771,071   102,400,002   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         874,371,072   913,430,527    39,059,456  83 Linux
/dev/sda6         913,432,576   921,243,647     7,811,072  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7    *    921,245,696   922,220,543       974,848  ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda8         922,222,592   976,771,071    54,548,480  83 Linux


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop3                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop4                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop5                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop6                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop7                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        B0C83C75C83C3BC2                       ntfs       
/dev/sda2        6E0C2CDD0C2CA257                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        F6C668AEC66870B3                       ntfs       New Volume
/dev/sda5        2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede   ext4       
/dev/sda6        ef82a317-ac35-4498-a65c-8d6469f4ab7a   swap       
/dev/sda7        3E95-F2AC                              vfat       
/dev/sda8        94281f85-1db7-4aba-a334-5074acb2214a   ext4       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda5        /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda8        /home                    ext4       (rw,relatime)


=========================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-18-generic root=UUID=2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-18-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-18-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.18.0-18-generic-advanced-2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.18.0-18-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-18-generic root=UUID=2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-18-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-18-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.18.0-18-generic-recovery-2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.18.0-18-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-18-generic root=UUID=2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-18-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-15-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.18.0-15-generic-advanced-2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.18.0-15-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-15-generic root=UUID=2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-15-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.18.0-15-generic-recovery-2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.18.0-15-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-15-generic root=UUID=2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)"{
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda5/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2fbabe25-d094-4d4a-8d6a-0dcbf2dd7ede /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda7 during installation
#UUID=3E95-F2AC  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=94281f85-1db7-4aba-a334-5074acb2214a /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=ef82a317-ac35-4498-a65c-8d6469f4ab7a none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda4

00000000  33 6f 56 d2 55 04 32 9d  49 e7 21 a5 8c b5 54 45  |3oV.U.2.I.!...TE|
00000010  20 8a 29 57 2f 79 51 6b  15 b9 24 f9 dc 1d 9a 4f  | .)W/yQk..$....O|
00000020  d2 58 bf f4 b5 ff d7 a7  9b 3b ae b1 a6 91 e9 ef  |.X.......;......|
00000030  c8 d9 7a 59 03 0a 21 44  cd 24 f3 13 12 aa 8e 6e  |..zY..!D.$.....n|
00000040  00 1e 8a d2 72 2a dc d9  04 0c 27 e3 d3 2d 5a ff  |....r*....'..-Z.|
00000050  f1 ea 00 4e 2a ea 60 6a  01 5f f9 1f 37 a2 94 ad  |...N*.`j._..7...|
00000060  be 21 6f ef 3f 7c b5 0a  f7 ae 5c 55 07 b8 e5 20  |.!o.?|....\U... |
00000070  dd df 51 94 4b 1f 5a bb  f8 51 b1 78 d0 b3 67 12  |..Q.K.Z..Q.x..g.|
00000080  0b fc 8f db 2c 86 8d 42  3a 89 14 89 b6 dc ad 01  |....,..B:.......|
00000090  bc 5a f7 9c c9 ad b4 31  61 7e 57 a4 cd 79 0a 79  |.Z.....1a~W..y.y|
000000a0  ba ce 17 1a 13 60 8d 6d  f9 0a df b3 76 d1 06 73  |.....`.m....v..s|
000000b0  f3 19 3a 6b d5 6a 0a cd  5e 93 39 a8 04 b3 cb 8a  |..:k.j..^.9.....|
000000c0  a7 9f 54 30 9c 94 e7 c6  ea cf 22 4e d4 a0 a2 37  |..T0......"N...7|
000000d0  6b 4b fd 95 c8 8d 79 04  9a c2 bb a6 22 9c 16 f8  |kK....y....."...|
000000e0  89 18 7e 96 3b 38 e2 ab  30 15 ed 7a a6 1a 1f 73  |..~.;8..0..z...s|
000000f0  2b be 2b e5 37 ce 6d da  23 d4 61 06 89 4c 9f d5  |+.+.7.m.#.a..L..|
00000100  84 58 54 c4 96 74 3e d7  a9 28 7b 20 22 14 3d 60  |.XT..t>..({ ".=`|
00000110  b6 b3 49 d0 4d 06 fc 18  3b e1 9e 21 70 e3 f7 25  |..I.M...;..!p..%|
00000120  57 ca b7 fc 91 6d b8 85  a3 43 9a 11 48 98 50 6b  |W....m...C..H.Pk|
00000130  3c 95 5b 67 b2 d5 25 0a  7e 6a 5e c5 88 5f dd 0f  |<.[g..%.~j^.._..|
00000140  78 e5 aa 41 22 a4 f8 8e  2d 40 44 c1 98 aa 33 01  |x..A"...-@D...3.|
00000150  7e 6d b5 e5 19 15 51 40  14 16 98 04 b1 84 38 1d  |~m....Q@......8.|
00000160  47 e7 be e0 19 a6 d7 e4  c8 5c 91 94 6a 59 9d cf  |G........\..jY..|
00000170  41 cc 68 3a 7f 7a 39 ea  27 f5 cc 01 30 72 cf 87  |A.h:.z9.'...0r..|
00000180  00 26 e1 88 a1 88 b6 84  62 ba d3 c8 d5 41 b9 e1  |.&......b....A..|
00000190  72 fd ae 5f 1c 02 65 f5  b8 74 2a 89 cb a2 b1 3f  |r.._..e..t*....?|
000001a0  ff f3 20 4f 9a 7c 0f 50  0b f6 7b 1b 08 a8 51 4b  |.. O.|.P..{...QK|
000001b0  8e fb 0a 51 84 d2 26 b6  9c 07 56 17 56 4c 00 fe  |...Q..&...V.VL..|
000001c0  ff ff 83 fe ff ff 02 00  00 00 00 00 54 02 00 fe  |............T...|
000001d0  ff ff 05 fe ff ff 02 00  54 02 00 38 77 00 00 00  |........T..8w...|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-qpWbVfHM/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: @AtomiX84: Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1141717/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Ubuntu (and thus grub) was installed in UEFI mode and Windows 10 was upgraded from a Windows 7 in BIOS mode.

Both boot systems are not compatible with one another and now you need to go into your BIOS settings to choose between legacy mode to boot Win10 and UEFI for Ubuntu.

If this is a fresh install, set your system back to BIOS boot mode and install Ubuntu in BIOS mode too and then Windows will show up in grub automagically.  **:-)**

This also has nothing to do with Ubuntu, so I'll close your question as off topic next.

### ¯\_(ツ)_/¯